# Как создать вычисляемые столбцы в DataGrid?

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

Я создал простой DataGrid с пятью столбцами. Значение в одном столбце зависит от значений в других столбцах, как мне создать такую зависимость?

Вот пример структуры, которая хранится в строках таблицы:

```
public class ColorItem
{
    //  Constructor
    /*
     *      ColorItem constructor
     *      Params: color name, color
     */
    public ColorItem(string color_name, Color color)
    {
        ItemName = color_name;
        RChanel = color.R;
        GChanel = color.G;
        BChanel = color.B;
    }

    //  Item name
    public string ItemName { get; set; }
    //  Item color (dependable item)
    public Brush ItemColor { get { return new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromRgb(RChanel, GChanel, BChanel)); } }
    //  Item r chanel
    public byte RChanel { get; set; }
    //  Item g chanel
    public byte GChanel { get; set; }
    //  Item b chanel
    public byte BChanel { get; set; }

}
```

DataGrid создается программно:

```
    m_dictionary_data = new DataGrid();
    this.Content = m_dictionary_data;
    {
            m_dictionary_data.Columns.Add(new DataGridTextColumn() { Header = "Color name", Binding = new Binding("ItemName")});
            m_dictionary_data.Columns.Add(new DataGridTextColumn() { Header = "Color", Binding = new Binding("ItemColor")});
            m_dictionary_data.Columns.Add(new DataGridTextColumn() { Header = "R", Binding = new Binding("RChanel")});
            m_dictionary_data.Columns.Add(new DataGridTextColumn() { Header = "G", Binding = new Binding("GChanel")});
            m_dictionary_data.Columns.Add(new DataGridTextColumn() { Header = "B", Binding = new Binding("BChanel")});
    }

   ObservableCollection<ColorItem> color_records = new ObservableCollection<ColorItem>() {};
   // Filling color_records
   m_dictionary_data.ItemsSource = color_records;
```

(ColorItem реализует INotifyPropertyChanged интерфейс (в коде не показано))

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Небольшой пример показывающий идею релизации. Допустим у нас будут 2 поля для имени и фамилии, а в третьем они будут отображаться вместе. Для начала создадим `VM-ку` для отображаемых данных.

```
class ItemVm : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string _firstName;
    private string _lastName;

    public string FirstName
    {
        get { return _firstName; }
        set
        {
            _firstName = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(FullName));
        }
    }

    public string LastName
    {
        get { return _lastName; }
        set
        {
            _lastName = value; 
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(FullName));
        }
    }

    public string FullName
    {
        get
        {
            return $"{FirstName}  {LastName}";
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

И главную `Vm` , которая будет хранить коллекцию этих данных и привязываться к `DataGrid`:

```
class MainVm
{
    public ObservableCollection<ItemVm> ItemVms { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<ItemVm>();
}
```

Теперь главную `Vm` привязываем к окну в `app.xaml.cs`(не забудьте удалить в `app.xaml` строку с `StartupUri`):

```
protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnStartup(e);
        new MainWindow() { DataContext = new MainVm()}.Show();
    }
```

Ну и наконец сам `DataGrid`:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    Title="MainWindow"
    Width="525"
    Height="350"
    d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance local:MainVm,
                                     d:IsDesignTimeCreatable=True}"
    mc:Ignorable="d">
<Grid>
    <DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="True"
              CanUserAddRows="True"
              ItemsSource="{Binding ItemVms}" />
</Grid>
```

Так выглядит результат:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

UPDATE. Чтобы создать `DataGrid` программно и привязать к нему данные нужно сделать вот так:

```
        var dataGrid = new DataGrid()
        {
            Columns = { new DataGridTextColumn() { Header = "First Name", Binding = new Binding("FirstName") },
                        new DataGridTextColumn() { Header = "Last Name", Binding = new Binding("LastName") },
                        new DataGridTextColumn() { Header = "Full Name", Binding = new Binding("FullName") }},
            AutoGenerateColumns = false
        };
        this.Content = dataGrid;

        ObservableCollection<ItemVm> items = new ObservableCollection<ItemVm>();
        dataGrid.ItemsSource = items;
```

---

Просто замените ваш код на вот этот:

```
var m_dictionary_data = new DataGrid()
        {
            AutoGenerateColumns = false,
            CanUserAddRows = true
        };
        this.Content = m_dictionary_data;
        {
            m_dictionary_data.Columns.Add(new DataGridTextColumn() { Header = "Color name", Binding = new Binding("ItemName") });
            m_dictionary_data.Columns.Add(new DataGridTextColumn() { Header = "Color", Binding = new Binding("ItemColor") });
            m_dictionary_data.Columns.Add(new DataGridTextColumn() { Header = "R", Binding = new Binding("RChanel") });
            m_dictionary_data.Columns.Add(new DataGridTextColumn() { Header = "G", Binding = new Binding("GChanel") });
            m_dictionary_data.Columns.Add(new DataGridTextColumn() { Header = "B", Binding = new Binding("BChanel") });
        }

        ObservableCollection<ColorItem> color_records = new ObservableCollection<ColorItem>() { };
        // Filling color_records
        m_dictionary_data.ItemsSource = color_records;
```

И `ColorItem`:

```
 public class ColorItem : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private byte _rChanel;
    private byte _gChanel;
    private byte _bChanel;
    //  Constructor
    /*
     *      ColorItem constructor
     *      Params: color name, color
     */

    public ColorItem()
    {

    }
    public ColorItem(string color_name, Color color)
    {
        ItemName = color_name;
        RChanel = color.R;
        GChanel = color.G;
        BChanel = color.B;
    }

    //  Item name
    public string ItemName { get; set; }
    //  Item color (dependable item)
    public Brush ItemColor { get { return new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromRgb(RChanel, GChanel, BChanel)); } }
    //  Item r chanel
    public byte RChanel
    {
        get { return _rChanel; }
        set
        {
            _rChanel = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(ItemColor));
        }
    }

    //  Item g chanel
    public byte GChanel
    {
        get { return _gChanel; }
        set
        {
            _gChanel = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(ItemColor));

        }
    }

    //  Item b chanel
    public byte BChanel
    {
        get { return _bChanel; }
        set
        {
            _bChanel = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(ItemColor));

        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещен в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/43900/discussion-on-answer-by-lightness------datagrid).